# LNK2005 Error When Implementing static Fields In a Struct

Tags: c++, struct, static, field, lnk2005

I get LNK2005 "public: static struct Color Color::Black already defined in ***.obj

Color.h file contents:

```
#pragma once

struct Color
{
    Color(float r, float g, float b) : R{ r }, G{ g }, B{ b }, A{ 1.0f }{}

    float R;
    float G;
    float B;
    float A;

    static Color Black;
};

Color Color::Black = Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

What would be the correct way of implementing a bunch of default colors like black, white, red, green, etc?

Comment: Same way that you defined `Black`? I don't see the problem.

Comment: Except that you should move `Color::Black` out of the header file. and you should declare it `const`.

Comment: Another solution would be to initialize `Black` when you declare it in `Color`.

Comment: Either move the definition of the static member variable (`...::Black = Color...`) to an implementation file or add the `inline` modifier. Personally I'd go with making the variable `constexpr` which implies `inline` (requires you to make the constructor `constexpr` as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for this

```
// header file
#pragma once

struct Color
{
    Color(float r, float g, float b) : R{ r }, G{ g }, B{ b }, A{ 1.0f }{}

    float R;
    float G;
    float B;
    float A;

    static const Color Black;
    static const Color Red;
    // etc
};

// cpp file

const Color Color::Black = Color(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
const Color Color::Red = Color(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
// etc
```

Comment: Initializing the static fields outside of the header file worked, thank you.